# Is PHP clever enough not to serialize multiple times a long array key?

Tags: php, serialization

For example,if  I have an array like this:

```
[ [ 'longkeyname' => 1, 'otherlongkeyname' => 2 ],
  [ 'longkeyname' => 211, 'otherlongkeyname' => 33 ],
  ...
]
```

then does PHP recognize *longkeyname* and *otherlongkeyname* are repeated many times, so it stores the key names only once and replaces them further with some generated integer key?

Or does it store *longkeyname* and *otherlongkeyname* for every item even if the array has e.g. a million items?

Comment: No it does not compress anything during serialization.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly with "serialize". If you refer to the function with that name, you can just `var_dump()` its output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stores longkeyname and otherlongkeyname for every item even if the array has a million items. 
The key of a PHP array is not tied to the length.

Comment: Thanks, seems wasteful to store such repeating info. Serialize could have some flag where the user could indicate the keys do not change.